# How can I sort a stacked bar charts on the total value of the bar with echarts?

Tags: echarts

I'm creating a stacked bar charts with apache echarts with the transform functionality.
I would like the bar chart to be sorted based on the total value of the barchart.

Please find an example here, or in [codepen](https://codepen.io/johanroe/pen/YzBXpGV)

```
{
  dataset: [
    {
      source: [
        {
          carrierName: "jopie",
          transportLeg: "Retour",
          totalWeight: 20,
        },
        {
          carrierName: "jopie",
          transportLeg: "Inbound",
          totalWeight: 20,
        },
        {
          carrierName: "def",
          transportLeg: "Retour",
          totalWeight: 15,
        },
        {
          carrierName: "def",
          transportLeg: "Inbound",
          totalWeight: 15,
        },
        {
          carrierName: "def",
          transportLeg: "Replenish",
          totalWeight: 15,
        },
        {
          carrierName: "ghi",
          transportLeg: "Inbound",
          totalWeight: 10,
        },
      ],
      dimensions: ["carrierName", "transportLeg", "totalWeight"],
    },
    {
      transform: [
        {
          type: "filter",
          config: {
            dimension: "transportLeg",
            value: "Inbound",
          },
          print: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      transform: [
        {
          type: "filter",
          config: {
            dimension: "transportLeg",
            value: "Replenish",
          },
          print: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      transform: [
        {
          type: "filter",
          config: {
            dimension: "transportLeg",
            value: "Retour",
          },
          print: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  xAxis: {
    type: "category",
    datasetKey: `carrierName`,
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      encode: {
        x: "carrierName",
        y: "totalWeight",
      },
      type: "bar",
      stack: "x",
      name: "123",
      datasetIndex: 1,
    },
    {
      encode: {
        x: "carrierName",
        y: "totalWeight",
      },
      type: "bar",
      stack: "x",
      name: "123",
      color: "yellow",
      datasetIndex: 2,
    },
    {
      encode: {
        x: "carrierName",
        y: "totalWeight",
      },
      type: "bar",
      stack: "x",
      name: "123",
      color: "green",
      datasetIndex: 3,
    },
  ],
}
```

The total should in this case the sum for all transportLegs, that would be

| carrierName | totalWeight |
| --- | --- |
| def | 45 |
| jopie | 40 |
| ghi | 10 |

I have tried adding another transform sort step, both as a first and final step of the transform chain like so:

```
{
  transform: [
    {
      type: "sort",
      config: {
        dimension: "totalWeight",
        order: "desc",
      },
      print: true,
    },
  ],
}
```

But this does not seem to change anything to the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the bars sorted in the horizontal axis (and not inside the stack) you can precompute the totals and sort your dataset by hand based on the carrierName.

This could look something like [this](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygiBTWBeGBtAUDGAb3wJmAQCcKBLVCgOQQFtUAuGAcgCsQAHWjgBoSBKBQSReIClAAyqAObsOAJXQgArhSEiYUEMgA2AdVTUFACyjsATAAYSAX2EFipMpRp1GLZT36oOu5iEhBSMvJKnACSYABGmmBwQaT6RqbmVrYOBM4kbqTkVLQMzGyccKgAZimi4pLScorKavpatXoGCCZmltYwAIwArE4uRLpFXqW-FdUdIQ0RzTHxicljol09mf3Do_kTniU-5RyVNRt69WGNkS2ovIaoYNQQFvNbGX3se7ljBQRJscyspLNR5tdwk0ohxYgkNEkPulellBjkYI5cABdADcuFwoEgsAgGiYLDgXysMCwiGQaCgADoKKg4BpgKgABQkKoI4BQajgGAc6hgKB0cnUJCoQRkLTM0XRMVMACU43chOgHmKdGpMBFYooEqlDKqIrgHKBOowAD4tVMGWAytSMFhgHLnlBFagmAzLdNUMq8e5qFUhX7VQDCkc6AySUwYABqV3uhVKhlpbqUqBB0iOGCoQxoNXuPWi8UsyVihm8DRvDmER0zN1UD1en1-k4yuPsZvyz1pjPbPqOQO6THuZlQLRgUsGo1inN5AjYLG4Ue4WkodCxxocjkIGVxVU2mBx8lZk1mi3RijU21-h1Ol1YOK-m8nZWx0kwAC0p9J54ooyppJNe2q3ieD6NqgzpYAgb7gR-X4qvifD8oKWAFJu9LsHg7iRgQECaBQ7LsNh6CXAQcDUCwkACpAuEcB2ZRCJwCw3EsCisRwg5Zhwq7uEupAEVcoRVNITC4bo-HSSWUAAJ68KcpqGAaHQlmQ4CmlEIkadRtEQPRyjsVCkTqRpMAAG7dBopxwmsHCyYJlElrwNCiuwYi2U5GKyQJuaXCJ7HiYaUkWcW4UKUpygqWpLnqlp5jsLpJb6c8hngMZkK3Io5kadZhi2fcjzPK87w-X8FUwG5-qeRQ3nheOJb-ZVMkacFElhRZKWiIpynUKpdB5YUiU6VVVE0elRlsdlnHDe4BVFZwrTEY54WtetNUeVcDUWU17gtb5BBYmMAAeACCp2vMluhRac5Bigo0jyR05FQAA0qg8nsAABsxLA_fsBDyZd11EEJaBeBAXWuLJzygJUN3hadyj_YE8UwN9bGfEBa0lkJwR9cocSUOZ0AIMAADWyineZ0HKAMNgAMzmW9sSVCjgxjoFcNgAj5QpZzTHvixGNYzxOM7HjzmyXdxOky55NUzTdMgpwjMsy5oCGNIyjyQWOsAO6s0gW6ekkqCczY3O6CJ8MgIjEUlkLaPDeLvG47JBOpETnAk9oivIMrnC0y59Pq8z5na7rnAKMyzwm3S6Ds5b7BM2OJCro4OJAA):

```js
const summedWeight = dataset.reduce(
  function (intermediate, currentItem) {
    const carrier = intermediate.find(carrier => carrier.name === currentItem.carrierName);
    if (carrier) {
      carrier.sum += currentItem.totalWeight;
    } else {
      intermediate.push({name: currentItem.carrierName, sum: currentItem.totalWeight});
    }
    return intermediate;
  },
  []
);

dataset.sort((a, b) => summedWeight.find(carrier => carrier.name === b.carrierName).sum - summedWeight.find(carrier => carrier.name === a.carrierName).sum)
```

---

If you want the bars sorted inside the stack based on the value, this is currently not possible. [Here](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/18271) is an open issue which has not gotten any attention yet requesting this exact feature.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use this for now and subscribe to the open issue to see if this gets implemented in the future